# Finding the number of solutions in $\Bbb R$ of $cos(x)=\dfrac{x}{200}$

Tags: trigonometry

I came across this question on an entrance exam :
Find the number of solutions in $\Bbb R$ of $$cos(x)=\dfrac{x}{200}$$
As a first step I bounded $cos(x)$ to find that $-200\le x \le 200$ , so I guess that narrows it a bit and Im not sure if this means it has a finite number of solutions since $\Bbb R$ is continuous. I also tried studying $f(x)=cos(x)-\dfrac{x}{200}$ and it's derivative but I found it too messy, and since it's an entrance exam I don't feel like it requires a lot of work just some clever trick I can't figure out. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Make a graph of both. I can roughly say, either it will be 1 or 0 (number of solutions)

Comment: Oops, it'll have many solutions. My bad,  it will cross each trough and crest twice, except the extremities and near zero. So you have to 1. Find out, how many times cosine repeats.

Comment: Use that $\cos(x)$ is $2\pi$-periodic, consider how many times the graphs intersect in each interval, and how many such intervals there are that you need to consider.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hfzdvotxre

Comment: Remember that between two zero's of the derivative, there is one zero of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Using that all the roots of the equation satisfy $x\in [-200,200]$ can be roughly written
$$N_{roots}\approx \text{round}\bigg(\frac{400}{\pi}\bigg).$$
If there is an inaccuracy, then the maximum is per unit.